# duplicate and update a row in pandas given its index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to link patient's ID with patient images. Once patient could have more than one image attached to them. I have added a new column, image_ID in my dataframe that already has patient_ID.

So the code I've written below, only adds the last image_ID of a patient. How can I duplicate and add rows knowing their indices (the index that corresponds to the patient ID) so that I can duplicate all other information of the same patient for all of its images?

Since my `shuffled_balanced` data frame initially doesn't have the image_name column, I have created it and have set it to None. Please note `if row['patient_ID'] in sample` is due to the fact that `patient_ID` is part of `image_ID`.

I am also open to other ways of approaching this.

```
shuffled_balanced['image_ID'] = 'None'
for dirpath, dirname, filename in os.walk('/SeaExpNFS/images'):
    if dirpath.endswith('20.0'): 
        splits = dirpath.split('/')
        sample = splits[-2][:-6]
        for index, row in shuffled_balanced.iterrows():
            if row['patient_ID'] in sample:
                shuffled_balanced.at[index,'image_ID']=sample
```

Comment: if you would use SQL database then preferred method would be to create separated table and repeate rows only with `parent ID, image_ID` in this table.

Comment: you can use `df = df.append(row)` to add row again at the end. But you I don't know how it will behave when you run it in `for`-loop which use `.iterrows():`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html). Say you have two dataframes that look something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

patient_df = pd.DataFrame({"patient_id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                           "patient_name": ["Penny",
                                            "Leonard",
                                            "Amy",
                                            "Sheldon", 
                                            "Rajesh"]})

img_df = pd.DataFrame({"patient_id": [2, 3, 4, 4, 1], 
                       "img_file": ["leonard.jpg",
                                    "amy.jpg",
                                    "sheldon.jpg",
                                    "sheldon2.jpg",
                                    "penny.jpg"]})
```

```py
>>> patient_df
   patient_id patient_name
0           1        Penny
1           2      Leonard
2           3          Amy
3           4      Sheldon
4           5       Rajesh
>>> img_df
   patient_id      img_file
0           2   leonard.jpg
1           3       amy.jpg
2           4   sheldon.jpg
3           4  sheldon2.jpg
4           1     penny.jpg
```

You can merge them like so:

```py
>>> patient_df.merge(img_df, on="patient_id", how="outer")
   patient_id patient_name      img_file
0           1        Penny     penny.jpg
1           2      Leonard   leonard.jpg
2           3          Amy       amy.jpg
3           4      Sheldon   sheldon.jpg
4           4      Sheldon  sheldon2.jpg
5           5       Rajesh           NaN
```